# Postgresql - Passing a parameter in where clause vs passing value directly - Huge time difference

Tags: postgresql, performance, parameter-passing

I am using pgadmin 6.4.

I have written a function(with parameters) to insert into a table from a select query with multiple joins and a where clause that will take input from parameter.

I see a huge execution time difference varying from 1 sec to 4 min by passing the value and parameter in where clause respectively.

And obviously I have to use parameter in real time scenario. So, is there a way to optimize the query to execute faster when passing parameter in where clause?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn1(plan_id integer,customer_no text)
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
insert into tbl
select plan_id
,d.clmn1
,d.clmn2
,d.clmn3
,dtc.clmn4
,dtpmst.clmn5
,dtpmst.clmn6
,rpm.clmn7    
from dib.tbl1 dtm join dib.tbl2 dtpmst on dtm.profile_id = dtpmst.profile_id
join dib.tbl3 dtc on dtm.device_type_id = dtc.id
join dib.tbl4 rpm on rpm.profile_id=dtm.profile_id
join dib.tbl5 bm on  dtc.device_type = bm.device_type
join dib.tbl6 d on d.base_model = bm.base_model_code
where d.clmn3=customer_no ; -- this is slower takes 3 to 4 min
--where d.clmn3='12345';    -- this is faster takes 1 to 2 sec
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```